# Json schema for recursive structure not working

Tags: json, json.net, jsonschema

Here is my json schema. I want a recursive tree-like structure. But the response is passing even when I have invalid objects in the required array.

```
{  
   "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema",
   "properties":{  
      "Result":{  
         "type":"object",
         "properties":{  
            "Children":{  
               "$ref":"#/definitions/Node"
            }
         },
         "required":true
      }
   },
   "required":true,

   "type":"object",
   "definitions":{  
      "Node":{  
         "type":"array",
         "Items":{  
            "type":"object",
            "properties":{  
               "Children":{  
                  "$ref":"#/definitions/Node"
               }
            },
            "required":true
         }
      }
   }
}
```

To check that the JSON Schema validation will validate correctly , I deliberately put an invalid object inside the response -

```
{"Result":{"title":"title","Children":[{"invalidobject":"invalidobject"}]}}
```

But it is passing here  - https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/
What I actually want is Children to also have an array of Children and so on. So, only Children having objects with properties  - title and Children should be allowed.
Its passing for this response too -

```
{"Result":{"title":"title","Children":[{"title":45}]}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this schema. Note that this schema will allow children array to be empty even on the first level. After the first level, you have to allow children array to be empty otherwise, the schema will expect infinitely recursive data in order to pass validation.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "Result": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/node",
      "required":true,
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "node": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "string",
          "required": true
        },
        "Children": {
          "type": "array",
          "required": true,
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/node"
          }
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  }
}
```

In case you do not want to allow children array to be empty at first level try defining the first level separately like this.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "Result": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": true,
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/title"
        },
        "Children": {
          "minItems": 1,
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Children"
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "title": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "Children": {
      "type": "array",
      "required": true,
      "items": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/node"
      }
    },
    "node": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/title"
        },
        "Children": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Children"
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  }
}
```

Here the validation results for sample input JSONs validated from https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/

Input JSON:

```
{
  "Result": {
    "title": "title",
    "Children": [
      {
        "invalidobject": "invalidobject"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Validation result:

> Message:
>   Property 'invalidobject' has not been defined and the schema does not allow additional properties.
>   Schema path:
>    #/definitions/node/additionalProperties
>
> Message:
>   Required properties are missing from object: title, Children.
>   Schema path:
>    #/definitions/node/required

Inpot JSON:

```
{
  "Result": {
    "title": "title",
    "Children": [
      {
        "title": 45
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Validation result:

> Message:
>   Invalid type. Expected String but got Integer.
>   Schema path:
>    #/definitions/node/properties/title/type
>
> Message:
>   Required properties are missing from object: Children.
>   Schema path:
>    #/definitions/node/required